# Why colours on an amcharts Candlestick Chart Incorrect and don't Change?

Tags: amcharts

```
stockGraphs: [{
                closeField: "close",
                highField: "high",
                lowField: "low",
                openField: "open",
                fillColors: "#009900",
                lineColor: "#009900",
                fillColorsField: "#009900",
                lineAlpha: 1,
                fillAlphas: 0.9,
                negativeFillColors: "#000000",
                negativeLineColor: "#000000",
                title: "Price:",
                type: "candlestick",
                valueField: "close"'
},
```

The negative bars are coloured black. However the `positive bars are: #ff6600`.

Here is the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s8s8bbfd/

Comment: Try to remove this line: fillColorsField: "#009900"

Comment: @zeroin it is still orange `#FF6600`

Comment: Please, show us full source. It would be best if you could address directly to our support.

Comment: Added Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s8s8bbfd/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `useDataSetColors: false` to stockGraphs[0].

But the negative color doesn't apply on balloon. I don't understand why, with ohlc chart, it works...